# Implement Google-Play-Music like animation (3 bar spectrum beside playlist item)

Tags: android, animation

I want to implement something like this. So that I can have control over its color, number of bars, speed, etc.

Below is the animation that is shown next to the item that is currently playing in the Google-Play-Music app.

I will play this in a similar manner: next to the currently playing song in a music app.

[image]

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1558

Comment: Thanks! That's it man. If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Is that i can add more than 3 block?and how to reduce bar size also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a library called [Mini Equalizer Library for Android](https://github.com/claucookie/mini-equalizer-library-android) which provides this functionality.

[image: 1]

You need to add the view to your layout:

```
<es.claucookie.miniequalizerlibrary.EqualizerView
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/equalizer_view"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        custom:foregroundColor="@color/link_text_material_light"
        custom:animDuration="3500"/>
```

In order to start the animation, use this code:

```
EqualizerView equalizer = (EqualizerView) findViewById(R.id.equalizer_view);
equalizer.animateBars(); // Whenever you want to tart the animation
equalizer.stopBars(); // When you want equalizer stops animating
```

---

Also, there is another library called [AndroidVuMeter](https://github.com/HugoGresse/AndroidVuMeter) which seems to have more options.

[image: 2]

Just add the view to your layout.

```
<io.gresse.hugo.vumeterlibrary.VuMeterView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/vumeter"
    vumeter:stopSize="5dp"
    vumeter:speed="10"
    vumeter:blockNumber="5"
    vumeter:blockSpacing="20dp"
    vumeter:backgroundColor="#33b5e5"
    vumeter:startOff="false"/>
```

Comment: as a side note, the first library (Mini Equalizer Library for Android) you've linked use android View and animate it which is not really optimized considering the 0 complexity for this. The second library draw itself on canvas so the view consume less memory and use less resources to draw the rectangle.

Comment: Hi,how can i set block numbers in its xml file